# Soft close toilet seat issue

Tags: toilet

I know this is an odd question, but we just bought new Kohler toilets & I hate them because every time i get up, the seat sticks to my bottom enough to lift the seat up and then crash back down.  I'm told it's because of the soft close seat, but what can I do to fix this.  I've never had this issue with any other toilet (maybe because they are heavier).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Indeed this is an odd question, although I can see how it could get annoying. I don't know if it's on topic here, though.

Comment: Typically the toilet seat/lid are a separate item from the actual toilet. I have 3 identical Kohler toilets with 3 different seats/lids. Do you have a manufacturer/model # for the seat/lid?

Comment: Kohler - Cimmeron 1 pc - K-3619-96 - toilet came with the seat/lid

Comment: Typically soft seats like this : after sitting on them can 'stick'  because of body sweat / humidity. You might want to search for a different seat or inquire of Kohler if they have a different material more suited to prevent adherence. If the seat and yourself were cold and in a dryer environment - you would not have this condition. Likewise baby powder on the seat would prevent this condition - I know not a solution, however just think of the advantages :-) . [Just a little humor..]

Comment: you can make the rim heavier or slippery-er. or make your butt hairier. you could also work on your dismount technique; try leaning sideways as you lift to remove one cheek at a time. You also might be able to over-tighten the seat to the rim (or honey the hinges) making it a bit "stiff" to raise and lower, which might provide enough force to prevent the "lift and slap" action that's annoying you.

Answer (score 1):

The Kohler Cimarron toilet comes with a [Reveal Quiet-Close with Grip-Tight Bumpers Seat](https://www.us.kohler.com/us/reveal-quiet-close-w-grip-tight-bumpers-elongated-toilet-seat/productDetail/toilet-seats/841540.htm). You can swap that for any elongated seat, though obviously with a new toilet you wouldn't normally want to do that - except if it came with a regular seat and you wanted a soft-close seat, which this already is.

Supposedly, it has "Unique Grip-Tight bumpers hold the seat firmly in place and prevent shifting." That would seem to imply that it would do the exact **opposite** of what it is doing for you. Since it is brand new, I suggest [contacting Kohler directly](http://www.us.kohler.com/us/static/contact.jsp).

Comment: Kohler is sending me a wood soft close seat to see if this fixes the issue.  thanks for your help!